# How to append an integer iterator to the end of a string in conditional logic? C# winforms

Tags: c#, for-loop, conditional-statements

I'm trying to check through a list of strings that aren't in an array, and are instead stored as 7 separate variables.

[image: As follows]

Is it possible to have the i in this case, be appended onto the end of the floor variable in order to select based on that? So something like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (floor(i) ...)
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, by not storing them in numbered variables but in a collection. What have you tried?

Comment: @CodeCaster I ended up storing them in a collection, but was curious if this was a possible work around. Thank you for the response :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a collection of that strings wouldn't push your memory consumption (as strings are stored by reference, not data-copying). However, you'll get more suitable way to operate your data:

```
// init a collection container
var floors = new string[] {floor0, floor1, floor2, floor3, floor4, floor5, floor6, };

// old-school "array + loop"
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (floors[i] ...)
}

// or functional-style LINQ
var interestingFloorsIterator = floors.Where(...condition predicate...);
var interestingFloorsArray = floors.Where(...condition predicate...).ToArray();

// etc... etc... etc...
```

Comment: Perfect! I was thinking about this way, but I was curious if the way I was mentioning was possible. Thanks for you response.

Answer (score 0):

No such availability in C#. You can however change your code to keep a list of a list of strings (`List<List<string>>`). In this way, you can get the index you need to work with.

```
List<List<string>> floors = new List<List<string>>();
//... populate data
for (int i = 0; i < floors.Count; i++)
{
    List<string> floor = floors[i];
    //Perform work on floor
}
```

Since I can only see a snippet of your code, this is just a rudimentary example.

Comment: Your statement is wrong. Don't forget about reflection!

Comment: If the variables are *local* variables then no amount of reflection will save you. Besides, using reflection here assuming they're fields is not a good solution. The correct solution is to store them in a collection, to begin with.

Comment: Given the information we have about his current code, I went with my gut and called it as I saw it. If provided more, this could change.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen yes if the variables are local reflection won't help. But we don't know, thus the statement is wrong in my opinion.

The best solution is still storing them in a collection. Never the less, it _could_ be possible with reflection!

Comment: Ended up going for a collection, but thank you for the reply, nonetheless! :)